# VSCode opens a non-default terminal on startup

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode on Windows. I have git bash selected as the default terminal, and when I open a new terminal with the `+` button on the bottom panel, git bash opens, so that works fine.

However, when I open VSCode, the first terminal to open is ALWAYS Windows PowerShell. If I kill the terminal and open a new one with the *Ctrl + `* shortcut, Git Bash successfully opens.

Below is a screenshot of the relevant settings. As you can see, the Windows Exec and the Default Profile are set to git-bash.exe:

[image]

[image]

**The question**: How do I make VSCode open the default terminal on startup?

Comment: @TimothyG. that seems to be it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having this problem, it looks like a bug from the update.

I saw someone answer that `Before closing VSCode select Output instead of Terminal` was work for me.